# Pdf Tron error " Exception error: Pdf error not found" (React App)

Tags: reactjs, pdftron

I'm trying to embed Pdf tron to my React application. I'm receiving this error when I'm clicking on the tab I want to filter to find the relative pdf file.

```
const handleFilteredDocs =  (id)=>{
  const filteredDoc =  props.location.documents && props.location.documents.filter(doc=>{
      return doc.controlId === id
    })
    setFileteredDoc(filteredDoc)
   setPdfPath(filteredDoc[0].filePath) 
   
    WebViewer(
    {
      path: 'lib',
      initialDoc: `lib/pdf/${pdfPath}`,
      extension: "pdf"
    },
    viewer.current,
  ).then((instance) => {
    const { docViewer, Annotations } = instance;
    
    const annotManager = docViewer.getAnnotationManager();
    
    
   

    docViewer.on('documentLoaded', () => {
      const rectangleAnnot = new Annotations.RectangleAnnotation();
      rectangleAnnot.PageNumber = 1;
      // values are in page coordinates with (0, 0) in the top left
      rectangleAnnot.X = 100;
      rectangleAnnot.Y = 150;
      rectangleAnnot.Width = 200;
      rectangleAnnot.Height = 50;
      rectangleAnnot.Author = annotManager.getCurrentUser();

      annotManager.addAnnotation(rectangleAnnot);
      // need to draw the annotation otherwise it won't show up until the page is refreshed
      annotManager.redrawAnnotation(rectangleAnnot);
    });
  });
 
   
 
  
    

  
  }
```

I'm thinking is because the ref component didn't receive in time the pdfPath state and then throw the error. I've tried to place a separate button to load the pdf with the pdfPath correctly updated and in that case worked. What can i do make it render correctly there?
this is the error I get from the console:

```
(index)
Value
UI version  "7.3.0"
Core version    "7.3.0"
Build   "Mi8yMi8yMDIxfDZmZmNhOTdmMQ=="
WebViewer Server    false
Full API    false
Object
CoreControls.js:189 Could not use incremental download for url /lib/pdf/. Reason: The file is not linearized.
CoreControls.js:189 
{message: "The file is not linearized."}
CoreControls.js:189 There may be some degradation of performance. Your server has not been configured to serve .gz. and .br. files with the expected Content-Encoding. See http://www.pdftron.com/kb_content_encoding for instructions on how to resolve this.
CoreControls.js:189 There may be some degradation of performance. Your server has not been configured to serve .gz. and .br. files with the expected Content-Encoding. See http://www.pdftron.com/kb_content_encoding for instructions on how to resolve this.
CoreControls.js:189 There may be some degradation of performance. Your server has not been configured to serve .gz. and .br. files with the expected Content-Encoding. See http://www.pdftron.com/kb_content_encoding for instructions on how to resolve this.
81150ece-4c18-41b0-b551-b92f332bd17f:1 
81150ece-4c18-41b0-b551-b92f332bd17f:1 PDFNet is running in demo mode.
81150ece-4c18-41b0-b551-b92f332bd17f:1 Permission: read
CoreControls.js:922 Uncaught (in promise) 
{message: "Exception: ↵  Message: PDF header not found. The f… Function     : SkipHeader↵    Linenumber   : 1139↵", type: "InvalidPDF"}
```

Thank you guys for any help I will get on this!

Answer (score 0):

The value of "pdfPath" isn't set to "filteredDoc[0].filePath" yet after you call "setPdfPath" (it'll still be the initial state till the next render). One thing you can do is pass a callback function when using "setState" to call "WebViewer()" after "pdfPath" has been updated

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Also there is a guide on how to add PDFtron to a React project in the following link
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/react/

One thing to note, is it's does the following

```
useEffect(() => {
  // will only run once
  WebViewer()
}, [])
```

By doing the above, "WebViewer" is only initialized once. It might be a good idea to do something similar and use "loadDocument" (https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/best-practices/#loading-documents-with-loaddocument) when switching between documents instead of reinitializing WebViewer each time the state changes